# Apache Virtual Hosts - Map different paths of the same domain to different sites

Tags: apache-http-server

I a running Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)

I want to use only one domain name.

I would like to map different sites to different paths after the domain name.

For example:

mydomain.com/test001 maps to /var/www/test001/public

mydomain.com/test002 maps to /var/www/test002/public

I've already tried many different virtual host configurations but none of them worked.

so now I am trying to map mydomain.com/test002 to /srv/public , as below:

Alias /test002 /srv/test002/public_html

```
<Directory /srv/test002 /public_html>

   Order Allow,Deny

   Allow from all

   Options FollowSymLinks

</Directory>
```

the first site woks but the second site index page only works and if I tried to redirect to another page it will give '404 page not found'

the .htaccess of the second site is :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test002/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule !.(js|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|map)$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
```

It is very  weird, I have been working on it all day and no solution yet and couldn't find anything helpful on the web.

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work?:

```
<VirtualHost host_details...>
  Alias       /test001   "/var/www/test001/public"
  Alias       /test002   "/var/www/test002/public"
  ...
  <Directory /var/www/test001/public>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/test002/public>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
  ...
</vhost>
```

Comment: Given that it's Apache 2.4, I would also suggest taking the opportunity to switch to `Require all granted` instead of the 2.2-compat Order+Allow.

Comment: Is this done with the original vhost of 'mydomian.com' conf file or should I create a different conf file for the Aliases as:    mydomain.com.conf, test.conf

Comment: You only have one vhost, so `mydomain.com`or whatever it is called, just as I have shown.

Comment: yes , it works thanks for you help @Bib